# How to connect to Azure Synapse?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

How am I supposed to connect to Azure Synapse?  Is there a page on the portal (and where is it)?  Is it from Management Studio (and how to I set that up)?

Answer (score 3):

from azure portal click overview open synapse studio:

https://web.azuresynapse.net/en-us/workspaces
click the sql pool and then you will see the endpoint and the connection string

enter the connection string in data studio

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can connect from either SQL Server Management Studio or Azure Data Studio using its dedicated SQL endpoint:

`tcp:myazuresynapseinstance.database.azuresynapse.net,1433`

The Properties blade in the Portal will display other endpoints.

You can also connect from the Portal - under the "Getting Started" section there is an "Open Synapse Studio" link.

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure Portal in the Overview you see the "Dedicated SQL Endpoint" and the "Serverless SQL Endpoint", and you can connect to these through SSMS, any other SQL Server client tool, or you can navigate to the "Workspace Web URL" and use the online editor for SQL Scripts there.