# Is it possible to connect to Azure Synapse with SSMS?

Tags: sql, ssms, azure-synapse

I connected Synapse to Azure data studio by following the steps that are mentioned at this link:

[How to connect to Azure Synapse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66518001/how-to-connect-to-azure-synapse)

But when I try to follow the same steps and connect Synapse to SSMS, I get following error:

I just wanted to know if I'm missing something here:

[image: azure data studio and synapse successful connection]

[image: ssms and synapse connection error]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I have definitely connected to Azure Synapse Analytics, dedicated SQL pools and serverless SQL pools with SSMS.  It works.  Double-check you have the latest version of SSMS, and try specifying the database in the Options section.  If you do not do this, it will try and connect you to master.

Answer (score 0):

Provide only server name without port and tcp. You can copy the `server name` from the synapse workspace in the Azure portal.

[image]

**SSMS:**

[image]